# Prove that $ax \equiv 1 \bmod n \implies \gcd(a,n) = 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, gcd-and-lcm

I'm trying to prove the following but having difficulties.

> Suppose $a,x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then prove if $ax
>  \equiv 1 \mod n$ then $a$ is coprime to $n$.

I know what it means for the numbers to be coprime and using the congruence I can show that there exists $x,y$ that satisfies Bezout's lemma but I don't think that is sufficient here. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If $ax\equiv 1 \bmod n$ then there exists an integer $y$ such that $ax+ny=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. Hence $a$ and $n$ are coprime. Indeed, if $p\mid a$ and $p\mid n$ for some $p>1$, this would imply $p\mid 1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why are a and n coprime, huh?

Comment: @JiaoCtagon As I wrote, if they are not coprime, there exists a prime dividing both. This prime would divide $1$, which is nonsense. Instead of a prime, any integer $p>1$ also works.